# Hide/Delete last column if heading is None

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a DataTable with three columns:

```
<div data-bind="attr:{'id':'TableA'+Id()}" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height:auto; max-height:850px; overflow-x:hidden;">
                                    <table data-bind="attr:{'id':'TableAt'+Id()}" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Vehicle</th>
                                                <th data-bind="attr:{'id':'AC1'+Id()}"></th>
                                                <th data-bind="attr:{'id':'AC2'+Id()}"></th>
                                                @*<th data-bind="text:C1">Counter 1</th>
                                                    <th data-bind="text:C2">Counter 2</th>*@
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: dataList">
                                            <tr>
                                                @*data-bind="style: { backgroundColor: Color }*@
                                                <td>
                                                    <span data-bind="text: Name">4</span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span data-bind="text: C1">4</span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span data-bind="text: C2">2</span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
```

The names for the last two columns can be changed from a DropDown and only the last one can be None. Each time the user changes the name of the column, it must click on one button so the table will be refreshed according to the new changes.
When the name of the last column will become "None", the program should hide/delete the last column. 
I've tried this code inside the function for the reload data

```
if (item.C2() == "None") {
                //$('#TableAt' + item.Id()).DataTable().column(2).visible(false);
                //$("#TableAt" + item.Id()).DataTable({ responsive: true });
                //$('')
                var tbl = document.getElementById("TableAt" + item.Id());
                for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
                        tbl.rows[i].cells[j].style.display = "";
                        if (j == 2)
                            tbl.rows[i].cells[j].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }
```

but because my table has a length menu set initially to 10 when I want to see the other data it also displays the third column. For the first 10 data rows it works perfectly. It is any way to hide/delete the last column for the other data rows like for the first 10?

Comment: My mistake. Deleted the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all. Store the DataTable instance in a global variable e.g.

```js
myDataTable = $("#example").DataTable()
```

By that you don't need `document.getElementById("TableAt" + item.Id())`. Then call

```js
myDataTable.column([name of column or index]).visible(false);
```

I think that should do it.

Comment: Yes, that would be the dataTables way to do it. But it seems @Dana already have tried that solution, something similar is commented out.  If it not works,  something else is wrong. One should never, ever try to manipulate the dataTables internal logic by outside scripting.

Comment: @davidkonrad I suspected that the way to get the column was not working, and to fix that, I suggested storing the datatables instance. I'm not manipulating any internal logic. My suggestion follows an official example [link](https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html)

Comment: You misunderstand (or my english as bad - or both) It is me who have upvoted your answer and comment that it is the right way to go, is it not? The last part targeting "one" is a comment about how not to do it, as @Dana does.

Comment: @davidkonrad okay. Probably a misunderstanding. I'll leave it at that. Thank you for the vote.